# I can't get the input of submit type with Python Selenium

Tags: selenium

I try to get the id from an input submit button. When it's verified that it's the right one, then I want to click it....but I can't find the input of submit type. 
I get NoSuchElementException.

Thank you guys in advance :-)

My HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./river.aspx" id="aspnetForm">            
    <!--CONTENT START-->
        <table width="100%" style="text-align: center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top">
                        <span class="CHeading">Choose a river in Stockholm:</span><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$btnChooseRiver00" value="River 00" id="ctl00_BodyContent_btnChooseRiver00" class="CButtonLarge">
                        <span><br></span>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$btnChooseRiver01" value="River 01" id="ctl00_BodyContent_btnChooseRiver01" class="CButtonLarge">
                    </td>      
                    <td style="vertical-align: top">
                        <span class="CHeading">Choose a river in Solna:</span><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$btnChooseRiver10" value="River 10" id="ctl00_BodyContent_btnChooseRiver10" class="CButtonLarge">
                        <span><br></span>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$btnChooseRiver11" value="River 11" id="ctl00_BodyContent_btnChooseRiver11" class="CButtonLarge">
                        <span><br></span>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$btnChooseRiver12" value="River 12" id="ctl00_BodyContent_btnChooseRiver12" class="CButtonLarge">
                        <span><br></span>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$btnChooseRiver13" value="River 13" id="ctl00_BodyContent_btnChooseRiver13" class="CButtonLarge">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

My python code:

```
try:

trInTable = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#aspnetForm > table > tbody > tr")
twoTdWithData = trInTable.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')

# I get 2 TD in next step
print(len(twoTdWithData))

#loop the 2 TD
for td in twoTdWithData:
    oneChoose = td.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
    idInButton = oneChoose.get_attribute("id")
```

except TimeoutException:
    print('TimeoutException')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('NoSuchElementException')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.
Here is the code.

```
form = driver.find_element_by_id('aspnetForm')
submitBtns = form.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td/input[@type='submit']")
for submitBtn in submitBtns:
    print submitBtn.get_attribute("id")
```

Comment: Thank you @supputuri! :-) 
I do this instead for form("aspnetForm")
theform = driver.find_element_by_id('aspnetForm')
        submitBtns = theform.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td/input[@type='submit']")
Now it’s working! Thanks again!

Comment: @supputuri: I am curious is there any thing present in selenium `driver.switch_to.form("aspnetForm")`???

Comment: Ha ha, that was a typo. I thought I was talking about frame all the time I was typing, updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this Kajal.